# How to write an SQL query that counts number of employees in a manager's department?

Tags: sql

The question is as follows:

> List the "manager's name" and the "number of employees" in that manager's department.

I am new to SQL and having some trouble writing a statement that queries the above statement.

This is the statement I wrote but it queries 6 employees as manager's when there should only be 3 manager's.

```
SELECT b.ENAME AS "Manager", COUNT(*) AS "Number of Employees"
FROM EMP e
JOIN EMP b ON b.EMPNO = e.MGR
GROUP BY b.EMPNO, b.ENAME;
```

The main question is how do I write it to only query the 3 manager's along with the employee count?

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: How do you know who is a manager?

Comment: What do your tables look like, do you have sample data? We need more than this to help

Comment: is it in mysql or microsoft sql server? Tag it approrpiate

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: The schema I have has a EMP table that includes the field job with manager being one of those jobs. Unfortunately I'm not at the computer that has the schema, so I will try my best to provide details.

Comment: WHERE b.MGR IS NULL?

Comment: If it helps I am using sqlplus and Oracle 11g Enterprise. The schema includes the tables: DEPT, EMP, BONUS, SALGRADE, CUSTOMER, ORD, ITEM, PRODUCT, PRICE. With EMP being the relevant table.

Comment: Why do you think the query doesn't work?

Comment: The EMP table includes the following fields: EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO.

Comment: @Adder The query works, but it list 6 employees 3 of which are not managers. I need it to run so that in only list the 3 manager's with the number of employees in their respective departments.

Comment: So you need to find a way to filter out those employees that are not manager. Hint: `where`

Answer (score 0):

```
  select count(distinct e.mgr), e.ename
  from emp e
  where e.mgr is not null;
```

try using distinct and mgr is not null.

Comment: when you use count(*) , counted also null value